# plupload not showing in IE but it works perfectly in other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, plupload

Plupload is showing in all browsers except IE. I can't even see the upload or add files button. I just see a blank. Any reason why? I have the latest flash installed (don't know if that's necessary). using windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and it turned out the paths to the flash and silverlight had an error in them. I didn't notice in other browser because it used the HTML5 runtime there.

Answer (score 0):

Same fix for me, but in my case, even more bizarre.

It worked for some IE explorer users and not for others, across different versions.

IE 9, would work because would use HTML5, unless you had installed silver light (the request would fail, but IE doesn't tell you unless you "start capturing" in the dev tools.

Other versions of IE, wouldn't work because it was looking for the Flash component.... unless we had the Google chrome frame which most of our IE users have...

It was driving us nuts, a nightmare to trace / debug !!!!

Thanks Mottokrosh

Comment: I would check some of the JavaScript code. I remember that IE6, some of the JavaScript code didn't work because it wasn't supported for those IE versions. (i think object.toSource() doesn't work for early IE versions).